# What to do if tasks are stuck in queued state in airflow? How to troubleshoot?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have run dags in airflow state but they are still stuck in queue? How to troubleshoot them ? They were running fine earlier but randomly started getting stuck in queue? Even if I terminate and mark them as failed and run a a new dag still it goes into queue!

Answer (score 1):

first step, you can check the task log.
Second step, you can write some trap in your dag & model for print log.
if still not solve, you cant use airflow test command to find where is the issue and try to sovle it.

airflow test [dag_name] [task_name] [datetime]